# Compiler Error CS0019: comparing two integers

Tags: c#

In C#, why does the first if statement gives me a compile error but not the second one? Can someone please explain?

1)       `if(num & 1 == 1) { Console.WriteLine("Test"); }`

This gives me: Error    CS0019  Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'.

2)

```
var x = num & 1;
if (x == 1) { Console.WriteLine("Test"); }
```

This compiles perfectly.

Comment: `if(num && 1 == 1) { Console.WriteLine("Test"); }` is the right one. You can't use bitwise AND in if-condition which requires `bool`, use comparison AND (`&&`) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

priority is by `==`. so `num & 1 == 1` should be `(num & 1) == 1`

[See here for operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx).